# Fatal error: Cannot declare class Product, because the name is already

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, static-content-deploy

This error pops up when I run php -dmemory_limit=-1  bin/magento s:d:c

**File; parseResource.php**

```
    <?php  
    
    class parseResource 
    {
          public $resourcePath = "";
          
          public $key = "";
          
          public $error = "";
          
          public $alias = "";
    
          function getResourcePath() 
          {
              return $this->resourcePath;
          }
     }
```

I have also attempted to add a name space in the file

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Plugin;
```

But this error pops up then

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Vendor\Modulename\Model\Plugin\parseResource, because the name is already in use in app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Model/Plugin/parseResource.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The information you provide are not enought to understand why the problem occures. I need the belove information to understant better.

1. Have you created the module as described in the MageDocs? As I see from your question, the name of the Module is Vendor_Module ?  Have you created the folders and the xml that the Magento 2 module need to have. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT1AnhDzYYM&ab_channel=MaxPronko) of the basic creation of the module. Also you have to run bin/magento set:up after the creation of the module.
2. As I see you want to create a plugin for some class, have you created the correct configuration in the di.xml and what is the class you want to add plugin?
3. Try deleting the files from the generated folder on the root folder. rm -rf generated/* Maybe there been changes you have done in older version of the file.

As it says its being used

> because the name is already in use

For some reason the same name of the class is being used somewhere else.

This should help you also, with this tool you can easily create your module with the functionality you need. https://mage2gen.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace in **`parseResource.php`**

**`app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Model/Plugin/parseResource.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Plugin;

class parseResource
{    
    public $resourcePath = "";
      
      public $key = "";
      
      public $error = "";
      
      public $alias = "";

      function getResourcePath() 
      {
          return $this->resourcePath;
      }
}
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**